# How can I Read/Write Images with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, node-modules

I'm pretty new to JS and I'm working on a Discord bot that uses Discord.js that uses COCO-SSD JS and requires me to Read/Write files from and to my PC.

I know this is probably not the best idea but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it.

Right now, I need a way to Read and write Images to and from my PC.

***NOTE:*** The files need to be Written to my computer from a URL. However if there's any way to circumvent having to downlead the images on my pc I would appreciate some help with that as well.

I'm using "fs", "https", and "fetch".

The problem with my method is that the pixels that I'm receiving from the images are **NULL** and so I cant do much with them.

Here's my current code:

**Sorry for the horrible formatting, english is not my first language and it's 2 AM here.**

```
const fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl;
const https = require('https');

function saveImageToDisk(url,path)
{
    var fullUrl = url;
    var localPath = fs.createWriteStream(path);
    var request = https.get(fullUrl,function(response) { console.log(response)
         response.pipe(localPath)
        });
    
}

saveImageToDisk("https://post.greatist.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg","./images/" + Date.now + ".png");

const img = fs.readFile("./images/" + Date.now + ".png", function(response){console.log(response)});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to achieve something like this using the module `node-fetch`, so I will provide an example below. I don't know what exactly you need this functionality for in your discord bot, but the below code will be able to properly save an image url to a specified path.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");

function saveImageToDisk(url, path)
{
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.buffer())
    .then(buffer => fs.writeFileSync(path, buffer));
    
}
```

I've tested the above example code and it works perfectly. As for the rest of the code, I do have a few fixes:

```
const filepath = "./images/" + Date.now() + ".png";
const imageurl = "https://post.greatist.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg";

saveImageToDisk(imageurl, filepath);
const img = fs.readFile(filepath, (err, response) =>{
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(response);
});
```

Specifically, the main issues were:

- `Date.now` is a function (hence it should be `Date.now()`)
- You should only create the filepath string once instead of doing so twice (for accuracy and simplicity)
- The callback of `fs.readFile` actually has its error object as the first parameter (so you were actually logging an error, or lack thereof, to the console instead of the response/file itself).

It is entirely possible that these issues alone were causing your code to not work, and that your original `saveImageToDisk()` was working fine. Just be aware that these issues were definitely causing problems with how you were reading the file, regardless.